# VSTS - Unable to get Iteration list

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get my VSTS project iteration list using the below REST API,

```
        string _personalAccessToken = "mypersonalAccessToken"; // this PAT has Project and team (read, write, and manage) and Work items (read and write) scope 
        string _credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", _personalAccessToken)));

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {            
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://*myUserAccount*.visualstudio.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _credentials);

            var response = client.GetAsync("DefaultCollection/*MyProjectName*/*MyTeamName*/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations?api-version=v2.0-preview.1").Result;

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);                
        }
```

My REST call is executing without any error (returning 200 code) with empty values. Though in my project, we have at least 50 iterations but i am not fetch those with above code.

I am not sure where i am making mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is ok.

Refer to these steps to check iteration of that team.

1. Go to admin page of that team
2. Select Work
3. Check the Iteration list
4. (Optional) Click Select iteration(s) to add iteration.

Update:

It retrieves the default team’s iterations if you omit the team name.

Default team: Go to admin page of team project > Overview> Change default team

Select iterations for default team: Go to admin page of team project > Work > Iterations> Click the default team’s settings.

[image]

If you want to get all iterations of team project, you can use [get the root iteration tree REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes#get-the-root-iteration-tree) or you can use this code directly (add/install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package):

```
 var u = new Uri("https://starain.visualstudio.com");
 VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "[pat]"));
            var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var workItemTracking = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectHttpClient projClient = connection.GetClientAsync<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectHttpClient>().Result;
           var projects= projClient.GetProjects().Result;
            foreach(var p in projects.Where(pro=>pro.Name=="Scrum2015"))
            {
                var iteration = workItemTracking.GetClassificationNodeAsync(project: p.Name, structureGroup: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.TreeStructureGroup.Iterations, depth: 5).Result;
                GetIterations(iteration);
            }


 static void GetIterations(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItemClassificationNode currentIteration)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentIteration.Name);
            if(currentIteration.Children!=null)
            {
                foreach (var ci in currentIteration.Children)
                {
                    GetIterations(ci);
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with above steps i see my team doesn't have any iteration list (probably that might be the reason for zero results). But all my iterations are in project level. I tried tweaking the REST call my omitting the team name but doesn't have desired result.

Comment: @Mahender It retrieves the default team’s iterations if you omit the team name. I updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks for updated details, am able to fetch my project iterations.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT  FYI, the link to get the "root iteration" is broken. We could probably check this instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-areas-and-iterations ??